# Leaving two siblings kittens alone for 2 nights

Tags: cats

An unexpected event happened, and I have too go spend two nights out of the house, but I want to make sure I do what is best for my two kittens.

They are both 2 months old and are siblings. They are used to spending every night in my large bathroom where they have their litter, food container, water container and cat tree. I am sure that nothing is dangerous for them in this environment. I planned on leaving them there for the 2 nights. I will be out of town leaving extra food, extra water and a second litter box in case. Do you think they will be fine together in the bathroom, as I would leave on the morning of the first day and come back on the night of the last day.?

The problem with bringing them with me is the fact that I have a lot of road to cover, and they really won't like being on the road with me, moving from one new house to another in the next few days, then coming back on the road to finally get home.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They should be fine, though they may be grumpy with you about not having had access to the rest of their territory -- or to you -- for that time.

Certainly I don't worry about leaving older cats alone for a long weekend if they're healthy, with lots of water (I have a bowl with a tank), dry food, and a recently cleaned litterbox. Longer than that and I'll hire a friend's kid to look in on them, change the litterbox, and give them treats.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll be sure to bring back a little toy gift to make sure they forgive me ^_^

Comment: Somewhat offtopic, but this reminds me: we all hate thinking about it, but the "Firemen: please save my __ cats" stickers are not a bad idea."

Answer (score 1):

I think they are too young. If you must leave them, have someone come in and check on them - make sure they have food and water, clean the litter box - and spend some time with them.

Older cats will usually do just fine as long as you put out enough food and water to be absolutely sure they won't run out. We have left cats for two days and nights with no problems. Given the number of cats we have, I will always put out at least one extra litter box to keep them from having to deal with a dirty litter box.

Even though we have left cats on their own from late on a Friday until late on Sunday, it is better to have someone check on them and we often do that.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have someone check in on mine daily when I have to go somewhere for even a day. 1 reason being, no matter how I have the water set up, they always manage to knock it over and play in it, leaving themselves none to drink. 2nd being what keshlam mentioned. you know your cats behavior best.